# How can you take a multi-class attribute and binarize it with weka?

Tags: data-mining, weka

I have an attribute, say `numberOfChildren` that can take on the values `0, 1, 2, 3`.  I want to preprocess the data in WEKA such that it becomes just 0 or 1, a `hasChildren` attribute, which is `0` of `numberOfChildren` is `0`, and `1` if `numberOfChildren` is greater than `0`.

How can you do this in Weka's preprocesser stage?

Answer (score 2):

You use [math expression](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Using+the+MathExpression+filter) filter.

Consider following arff file.

```
@relation NumberOfChildrenExample

@attribute A numeric
@attribute numberOfChildren numeric

@data
1,0
2,1
3,2
4,3
5,4
6,5
```

You use following command.

```
java  weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.MathExpression -unset-class-temporarily \
-E "ifelse(A>0,1,0)" -V -R 2 -i datasets\NumberOfChildrenExample.arff
```

- -V invert selection
- -R choose 2 column, hasChildren

otherwise this filter convert all numeric columns

```
@attribute A numeric
@attribute numberOfChildren numeric

@data

1,0
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,1
6,1
```

Since you want hasChildren attribute, you need to also use [Rename](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Rename+Attribute+Values)

Answer (score 1):

Try going to weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute and scanning the list.   Discretize might work but might also split your data in half.  MergeTwoValues might work for you if you merge the 3 to 2, then the 2 to 1, leaving you with 0 and 1.